# libgdx: Repeat a texture with offset like in HTML/CSS

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to repeat a texture but the texture should start with a offset rather then 0,0 (uv). I set

```
texture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);
```

and draw it with

```
backgroundBatch.draw(texture, 0, 0, stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight(), 0, 0, 1, 1);
```

There are two problems with this solution: First, the texture get skewed and I'm not seem to be able to specify a offset for the texture. The screen cordinate should be 0,0 but the texture uv should not start with 0,0

I want the same behaviour like background-position in combination off background-repeat in css.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to achieve this is using ParrallaxLayer and ParrallaxBackground classes

it optimised the background operation so that u dont have to worry about the performance

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ParallaxBackgound

Comment: Upvote for answer, but I thinks it's not quite exactly what I'm looking for, my background is just static decoration which I have to translate a little bit.